# resizing window and setting margins for minimum

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to create a tree graph, and since the "father" has a lot of "children" I'd like it to be a very wide graph. Therefore, I tried to resize the window with the windows option and set margins to zero width in order to have a wide graph. These are my program lines:

```
windows(heigth=7, width=14, record=TRUE, rescale="fit")
par(mar=c(1,0,1,0), omi=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(graph_name,layout=layout.reingold.tilford(tree))
```

I get a wide device window but the plot is in the middle and not wide-spreaded. What am I doint wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Noam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `igraph` uses a square aspect ratio, regardless of the size of the device.
You can disable this by setting the `asp` argument to `0`.

```
library(igraph)
g <- barabasi.game(100)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(g, asp=0)
```